# Reordering column groups in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a content that looks like this in large screens:

1 2

3 4

5 6

And I want it to look like this in smaller screens

1

2

3

4

5

6

But instead it looks like this:

1

3

5

2

4

6

How can i pull this off?

My html is something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p> Content1 </p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="Content3-img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p> Content3 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="Content5-img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p> Content5 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p> Content2 </p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="Content4-img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p> Content4 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="Content6-img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p> Content6 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant frameworks to the snippet I made you

Comment: Hello, sorry i did not understand what you are trying to say.  What do you mean by that? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Click edit, scroll down click edit above snippet, add Bootstrap and jQuery as needed

Comment: Oh, OK i did it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content1-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 1 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content2-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 2 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content3-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 3 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content4-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 4 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content5-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 5 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Content6-img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p> Content 6 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please comment your answer

Comment: the "col-sm-6" tags are descendants of the "row" container and by default define the order from left to right, from top to bottom

You had 2 total "col-sm-6" elements that had 3 elements, the first one was "content 1" and "content 3" and "content 5", the second one was "content 2" and "content 4" and " content 6"

I created 6 "col-sm-6" elements and put the content in order in them

Comment: Well that makes sense, i guess i went on and do the non-logical thing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap columns should be direct children of the .row bootstrap class. This way you can easily get the results you want.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <!--Your content-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <!--Your content-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <!--Your content-->
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you mean when i used more than one "row" element they kinda collided?